# Method POST not retrieveing data from form.

Tags: php, html, forms

I am currently learning Web-Design(HTML,PHP,Javascript) and I have created my own site a file called MySite.html.
I have a signin screen which uses POST method to send data to a file called signin.php.
For now it has a simple check which confirms whether data is inputted or not.
But when I enter the Username and Password, the script tells me that I haven't inputted anything.
Here is the code----->

```
<form name="signin"  action="signin.php" method="POST">
                <p><input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username"></p>
                <p>
                <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Password">
                <input type="submit" id="sgnin" value="Sign In">
                </p>
                <p id="small">
                <input type="checkbox" id="rem">Remember me.Forgot password?
                </p>
                <span><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </form>
```

The php script--->

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['pass']) && !empty($_POST['username'])       && !empty($_POST['pass'])){
echo 'Logged In';
 }else die("enter something");
```

?>

Plz Help!

Comment: If you are not getting form data.... always and i repeat always check if you have given the `name` attribute.

Comment: I'm very very sorry, I confused id with name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not giving name attribute to your form elements give it like this

```
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username">
```

and

```
<input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Password"  name="pass">
```